# How can I exclude "[" and "]" in a match like "[abc]"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
[a] [abc] test [zzzz]
```

I'm trying to get an array like so:

```
[0] => a
[1] => abc
[2] => zzzz
```

I've tried the following code:

```
var string = '[a] [abc] test [zzzz]';
var matches = string.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
    console.log(matches[i]);
```

But my console output shows:

```
[a]
[abc]
[zzzz]
```

I tried adding two non-capturing groups (`?:`), like so:

```
var matches = string.match(/(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])/g);
```

But I see the same matches, unchanged.

What's going wrong, and how can I get the array I want?

Comment: You're on the right track. [(.*)] will match the tokens, you're looking for, but those tokens have the square brackets. Just remove the brackets afterwards.

Comment: This is why I'm sad that JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds. `/(?<\[).*?(?=\])/` would be so much easier than hacking around.

Comment: @Kolink non-captured expressions look better IMO. `(?:\[{1}(?<stuff>.*)\]{1})`

Comment: @Phill Maybe, but they don't work with `/g`. Also, what on earth is that `{1}` about?

Comment: @Kolink https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` doesn't capture groups in global matches. I made a little helper for this very purpose.

```
String.prototype.gmatch = function(regex) {
  var result = [];
  this.replace(regex, function() {
    var matches = [].slice.call(arguments,1,-2);
    result.push.apply(result, matches);
  });
  return result;
};
```

And use it like:

```
var matches = string.gmatch(/\[(.*?)\])/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Regex

`[[]\s*(\b[^]]*\b)\s*[\]]`

Group 1 will contain an array of strings of all the text between your open and close brackets

## Example with regex only solution

Match will pull out all the matching substrings and display them, since this uses only regex it'll run slightly faster then using slice

```
  var re = /[[]\s*(\b[^]]*\b)\s*[\]]/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var results = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
    results[i] = matches;
    for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
      alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
  }


(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [a]
            [1] => [abc]
            [2] => [zzzz]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => abc
            [2] => zzzz
        )

)
```